# How C dynamic allocation works with the linker to define heap location

Tags: c, linker, malloc, heap-memory, gnu

I am working on an embedded system and have written a linker script to put certain sections in external ram. I am also attempting to setup the heap in external ram.

I can't seem to 'easily' find any documentation for gnu or libc that would inform me of what symbols may be expected to exist and what they should point to. If anyone could point me to the documentation or give a quick run down that would be great.

I would like to leave .data in ram and instead of having sbrk extend .data just use the .heap section in external ram instead.

Comment: Most `malloc` implementations call an OS function, à la `sbrk`, to obtain the heap.  So it's the OS and/or the `malloc` implementation I'd expect you to have to tinker with, not a linker script.

Comment: @SteveSummit - No OS in this instance. The libc sbrk function is called, my question I suppose relies more on how sbrk knows what areas to work in. For other sections this is done with symbols added into the linker. I'm trying to find out what symbols would be needed to get this to work.

Comment: Look at FreeRTOS source code. It has 4 or 5 different malloc implementations.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Thanks for the idea. I will look into that, hopefully that will give me a glimpse under the hood.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - No go. Looks as though FreeRTOS expects the memory defined for its own memmang unit.

Comment: You see that `ucHeap` there? You can place it in a dedicated section you define in your linker script, while placing that section in the memory you want..

Comment: @EugeneSh. No. I will need to get the full FreeRTOS source. I have a subset that came with my project.

Comment: I am talking about the simplest one `heap_1.c`. you can find it online without need to download the full blob

Comment: I found the issue. The stock _sbrk function expects the the heap to be below the stack at all times. However, in my setup the heap is above the stack and will never run into it. I needed to define the "end" symbol at the correct location for the heap and then override the stock function with one that only monitors to the end of the heap space, which I also defined in the linker. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting some more details and my solution in case anyone else comes across this.

I'm developing for the stm32f7 arm cortex uC. We developed a board with external ram and needed to stick the heap there.

The address for ram on the stm32 is 0x20000000. The address for the FMC(external ram) is 0x90000000.

the arm-none-eabi implementation of the _sbrk function extends the heap as well as checks for the colision of the heap and stack. In a normal build the heap and stack are both at the end of ram. However, once I moved the heap to external ram(0x90000000) it was always > the end of the stack and would cause _sbrk to fail.

Since the _sbrk function is weak linked it was a matter of re-implementing it to just verify that my allocations remained in my defined heap location.

Also to note: the linker must declare end to be the beginning of the desires heap location. I also added a _endheap symbol so I could constrain my heap to the desired memory section. Whether or not that is truly desired can be debated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you point to the resources you had to hit to get that solution? (Relevant pages of gcc/libc docs / lines of gcc/libc sources?)

Comment: This was almost three years ago. So I don't remember specifics. It was a combination of objdump'ing .a files and digging through linker scripts. I think I eventually found source for the libc library I was using but I can't be sure.